# Base color/material won't stay assigned after left click on window

Tags: materials

A week ago I got a problem when assigning materials to objects. The color just disappear when I click left mouse button.

[image][image]

Comment: In the second image you've removed the material slot, so your object can't have any material, but when you say that you left clicked, where did you left click?

Comment: Maybe left mouse button got assigned to a shortcut for something that removes the material?